# My SQL Query couldnt find results when using strings

Tags: php, mysql

Im fetching data from my database. When I look for account numbers with letters and numbers, it couldnt find any matches even though it has records.

SQL 1:

```
            SELECT * from account_files
            WHERE account_number = 'RA4724';
```

However, when I look for account numbers with only numbers in it, it was able to find records.

```
            SELECT * from account_files
            WHERE account_number = 2048;
```

The column is a varchar and Im using PHP version 8.1.5

Please note:
If you are too flag this question down, let me know why. Im really trying to ask questions without violating rules. So if I happen to miss any rules, I'd like to know. It's very confusing for users especially new ones like me why our questions aren't appropriate to ask. Thank you.

Comment: you should convert the numbers to string before passing them. try this -> `SELECT * from account_files WHERE account_number = "2048";`

Comment: Tried it, but it still couldnt find records.

Comment: There are no details on the problem and a short-sighted answer based on the guesswork. This entire page doesn't meet the quality standards. The only answer you can get here is quite obvious: the value in the database is NOT RA4724. but nobody in the world can tell what is it. Because it is your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when you are storing the string values in varchar field, you should make sure that the string does not have any trailing and leading spaces.
in php you could use the trim function as below.

```
$acnumber=trim($acnumber);  // where $acnumber has the account number string
```

and you can use the equal operator (=) in SQL only when want to match the exact string with exact case and spacing taking into consideration.

The best practice for storing the numbers with trailing characters is to create two separate fields in the table where you store number in the account_number field and and the trailing characters which may represent account category or customer initials for instance should be stored in the separate field say 'category' and when retrieving the data combine two fields into one string for viewing. This way, you can have a cleaner way of managing the data.

Further, you can also use 'LIKE' Clause in sql query to search for strings which may contain the specified characters in the query.

```
        SELECT * from account_files
        WHERE account_number LIKE '%RA4724%';
```

to check whether a character string matches a specified pattern.

'

Comment: Keep in mind these sorts of matches can be *slow* as every single row needs to be checked, a table scan.

Comment: Also, LIKE '%RA4724%' will match RA47249. A *very bad* suggestion if you ask me.

Comment: How were you able to derive that this was the appropriate solution when the question doesn't indicate that there are leading or trailing whitespace characters?

Comment: @YourCommonSense it didnt match like RA47249 in my case. What instances would it have that result?

Comment: `LIKE '%RA4724%'` will absolutely match `RA47249`, it will also match `BRA4724`.

Comment: [what](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql57/9a568186c3fb1f8e680c5267e04d5da0/)?

Comment: If it would match RA47249 or BRA4724, then it shouldnt be finding the exact record in my database, right? But it does. Im confused as to how it would match those.

Comment: @AaronAncheta because **you don't have** RA47249 or BRA4724 in your database yet (but it's only a matter of time)?